# Variable templates only available with C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have declared a struct which is:

```
template <typename T>
struct key{

T value;            
uint64_t less;  
uint64_t equal; 
uint64_t greater;

};
```

I am using an unordered_map to store the address of objects of the key type and their corresponding values. The syntax and declaration of the unordered_map is as:

```
template<typename T>
std::unordered_map<key<T> *,int32_t> htable;
```

When I compile my program g++ throws a warning: variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
My question is will my program be compatible with C++11 or do I absolutely have to specify the -std=c++14 flag? Is the above usage uncommon? What can I do to make it C++11 compatible? I need to hash the address of the key object and store information associated with it but key is a generic type and I don't know another way to implement this.

Comment: If the compiler tells you to use `--std=c++14` it makes sense that `--std=c++14` is required. This is not a trick question.

Comment: Are you actually trying to create a variable template? Do you even know what that is? Or are you just trying to create a single `unordered_map` object?

Comment: I am trying to hash the address of the struct "key" obtained by using memory from the heap and storing the corresponding value. I do not know what variable templates are.

Comment: Check out here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler states, variable templates were unavailable prior to C++14. I think [N3651](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf) is the paper which was accepted to add the feature (it may be a later version; I haven't verified which paper actually got voted into the standard).

If you need something which behaves *like* variable templates, although it has a different syntax, you'd use a function template with a `static` local variable and you'd return a reference to this variable, i.e., something like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::unordered_map<key<T>*, int32_t>& htable() {
    static std::unordered_map<key<T>*, int32_t rc;
    return rc;
}
```

When using it you'd use `htable<X>()` instead of using `htable<X>`. There are actually some pros and cons this approach:

1. On the positive side, the object gets initialized the first time it is actually used, i.e., there is no initialization order dependency.
2. As a result the object *may* get initialized only some time after `main()` was entered while the variable template objects would get initialized before `main()` is entered in all cases.
3. Since the initialization of function local `static` variables is thread-safe there *may* be a [probably] small cost involved every time the function is called.